# Entity Framework 6 Code First, Data Context Error when deployed, although same database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For my local and deployed version, I am using the same database ... I know that this is a bad practice, but I have no option as it is a running project and out of my hands.

I am using EF 6 code first approach, everything works fine in the local environment, but when I deploy the code, it shows a Data Context error. The same code and database is present in both environments, but it does not work.

But if I delete the migration history table, the error goes away. After deleting the migration history table, I have to unload the migration files as they will try to create tables that already exist.

Can someone provide me some knowledge on why this is happening, and why deleting the migration history table solves the problem. Some useful links and explanations would be really helpful.